# is there any uses of default xhtml and css properties?

Tags: css, xhtml

**For example:**

like `target = "_self"` in XHTML and `position:static` in CSS

Comment: What editor/locale do you use for HTML? Those curly quotes are syntactically wrong. They needs to be straight quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you write those when you've changed the setting in a wider context and need to set it back to the default for a particular case. For example with `target`:

```
<head>
    <base target="popup"/>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="foo">bar</a>                <!-- opens in popup -->
    <a href="bof" target="_self">zot</a> <!-- acts like a normal link -->
</body>
```

Or for `position`:

```
.floaty { position: fixed; }
#specialcase .floaty { position: static; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, there has to be a default value. This is the value applied if nothing else is specified. How else should the browsers know which value to apply?

And that is the same reason why using them in source code is useless (they will be applied anyways), unless you want to revise a prior antithetic rule.